# Pandas dataframe interpolation without missing data

Tags: pandas

How do I interpolate when there's no missing data in pandas? 
my original

[image]

my desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to play with index and then interpolate:

```
df.reindex(np.linspace(0, len(df)-1, 2*len(df)-1))\
    .reset_index(drop=True) \
    .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate('linear'))
```

**Explanation:**

There are two main steps: insert a `NaN` row every 2 rows and then interpolate.

1. Create a new list that we will use as index. It must start at the first `df` index, finish at the last `df` index and have a values gap of `0.5` (half of current `df` index gap). A simple solution is to use [`numpy.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
np.linspace(0, len(df)-1, 2*len(df)-1)
```

2. Use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to indexes create step 1.
3. (Optional) Reset the index using [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).
4. Apply an interpolation on all columns using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) followed by [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html)

---

**Code + illsutration**:

```
# import module
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4.18483, 4.15276, 4.13156, 4.1169], 'b': [99.90139, 98.91539, 97.9294, 96.9434]})

# Step 1
print(np.linspace(0, len(df)-1, 2*len(df)-1))
# [0.  0.5 1.  1.5 2.  2.5 3. ]

# Step 2
print(df.reindex(np.linspace(0, len(df)-1, 2*len(df)-1)))
#            a         b
# 0.0  4.18483  99.90139
# 0.5      NaN       NaN
# 1.0  4.15276  98.91539
# 1.5      NaN       NaN
# 2.0  4.13156  97.92940
# 2.5      NaN       NaN
# 3.0  4.11690  96.94340

# Step 3
print(df.reindex(np.linspace(0, len(df)-1, 2*len(df)-1))
      .reset_index(drop=True))
#          a         b
# 0  4.18483  99.90139
# 1      NaN       NaN
# 2  4.15276  98.91539
# 3      NaN       NaN
# 4  4.13156  97.92940
# 5      NaN       NaN
# 6  4.11690  96.94340

# Step 4
print(df.reindex(np.linspace(0, len(df)-1, 2*len(df)-1))
      .reset_index(drop=True)
      .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate('linear')))
#           a          b
# 0  4.184830  99.901390
# 1  4.168795  99.408390
# 2  4.152760  98.915390
# 3  4.142160  98.422395
# 4  4.131560  97.929400
# 5  4.124230  97.436400
# 6  4.116900  96.943400
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazing breakdown! I just wanted to know if there's an easy way to interpolate to floor/ceiling of those numbers, ex: 99,98,97,96 etc..

Comment: I think you can perform the interpolation and then, use [`np.floor`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.floor.html) or [`np.ceil`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html).